# How to search posts with an keyword (strings of strings)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to make a search field, and I'm already able to do searches, but it only returns posts that are typed with the same title or are exactly the same which would not be interesting, this happens in my conditional if (query !== post .title && query) return null
The ideal would be to search just one word and return similar posts, I've tried using the includes method as follows if (query !== post.title && query.includes(post.title) && query) return null but someone didn't work Would you help me ?

```
 {(() => {
          if (isLoading) return <LoadingBlock />
          if (!isLoading && postList.length === 0) return <NoDataWarning text='Nenhuma postagem encontrada.' />
          return postList.map((post, index) => {
            if (query !== post.title && query.includes(post.title) && query) return null //the problem is here
            return (
              <PostContainer position={index}>
                <PostBanner />
                <PostInfoContainer>
                  <span>
                    <AiFillCalendar />
                    {new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    <FaUserCircle />
                    {`${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}`}
                  </span>
                </PostInfoContainer>
                <PostTitle>{post.title}</PostTitle>
              </PostContainer>
            )
```

Comment: This pretty much says it all: `query !== post.title` - this literally says "_only return posts that are typed with the same title or are exactly the same_" - what happens with you remove that test? (what about upper vs. lower case since JavaScript is case sensitive).

Comment: `post.title.includes(query)`.

Comment: i tried post.title.includes(query) too, but when I add this condition the post that i type on input is removed and he returns all the others, and if I remove the query !== post.title the search doesn't will work because query in my logic is the value that comes from the input